# Input type submit hidden: Div Element css inside still Displayed

Tags: html, css, input, submit

Trying to hide a input type submit button to be hidden but still display the multiple div elements inside of the input type.
Attempted in css
.nk-feature-3 input[type=submit] display:none;

Display's no CSS applied to all Div Elements obviously, Tried a few other options.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

HTML
https://paste.ee/p/8xDFb
CSS
https://paste.ee/p/CDQeX
(Wouldn't let me paste as a snippet.)

Comment: I don't see any element named `.nk-feature-3`, nor any `input` elements in the HTML or CSS snippets. Also, it's not clear what you mean by "multiple div elements inside of the input type"; `input` elements don't take any children.

Comment: My bad, Accident. As i was trying to use a seperate div element.

I'll give an example of what im trying to do.
               <input type="hidden" name="submit"> <div class="nk-feature-2">
                    <div class="nk-feature-icon">
                        <img src="assets/images/paypal.png">
                    </div>
                    <div class="nk-feature-cont">
     <div class="nk-gap"></div>
                        <h3 class="nk-feature-title text-main-1">Pay Now</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
</input>

Hidden class hides all div elements.

Comment: Making the input hidden class not hide the css of all three div elements inside the input type.

Comment: I'm afraid you can't have a hidden parent with visible children in HTML. But, also, you shouldn't have children in an `<input\>` element, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Empty_element